# Reading a properties file that is OUTSIDE a jar file

Tags: java, dependencies, classpath, executable-jar

I've made a Runnable `.jar` file using eclipse, which has a class with `main` method in it. When you run the jar from command line with `java -jar myjar.jar` all it does is read properties off a `.properties` file and creates an instance of the class `com.vehicles.BMW`, so say we have a file (somewhere in the classpath IT MUST BE in the classpath) called `car.properties`, the file format looks like this :

```
car.className=com.vehicles.BMW
car.make=bmw
car.model=320i
```

so the code in my main looks as follows (assume we have an `Interface` Car) :

```
  public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
       Properties p = loadFileProperties( );
       String className = p.getProperty("car.className");
       Car car = (Car)Class.forName(className).newInstance(); //assume i handled the checked Exceptions on this line.
       //we'll just print these out
       sysout.....statement (p.getProperty("car.make"));
       sysout.....statement (p.getProperty("car.model"));
  }

  public static Properties loadFileProperties( ) throws IOException {
    //look for the file somewhere in the classpath.
    InputStream inputStream = MyWorkEngine.class.getClassLoader( ).getResourceAsStream( "car.properties" );
    Properties properties = new Properties( );
    properties.load( inputStream );
    properties.close();
    return properties;
  }
```

The file must be in the classpath that you specify when you run the jar. this code of course works fine when i have my own `car.properties` file in the classpath, that is (if it'included IN the jar) but i want to be able to give the `.jar` file to somebody else and it must be able to read THEIR `.properties` file when they run it on their machine from command line and tell it via `-cp` where to look for whatever dependencies it needs or whatever resources (including the properties file).

it must read it and create an instance their `Car` implementation, say `com.vehicles.MercedesBenz` and do the same thing as it does with mine. THAT person's file will also be named `car.properties`

I want to be able to give my jar to many people and they should point it to their classpath and it must run. How does one achieve this in the commandline ?

I've seen in another similar question, something that looks like this `java -cp myjar.jar:lib/* ClassThatHasMain` , I tried it and i failed, didn't understand it. So i decided to ask my own question.

Comment: Why dont you make your own classloader? apache's ant launcher project would be good starting point.